# PHP doesn't update included files when they are updated?

Tags: php, apache

In the layout file on my website I have the code

```
include('functions.php');
```

that refers to the functions file. Now I added a new function `example()` to the file and use it in the layout file.

So in the functions.php file is:

```
function example(){
        do something
}
```

and in the layout file:

```
include('functions.php');
example();
```

But after uploading to the server it drops an error:
"Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function example()" in the layout file

All other functions work fine. The problem only occurs if I want to update the functions.php file with new stuff. Then the layout file doesn't include the update but the older version.

I already tried to figure out if the server or PHP has internal caches or something else but it seems not so. So what could be the reason?

One year ago I renamed the file to functions2.php and it worked for one year. Now the file is already functions4.php and I can't go back to the older file names because they still do not work. :(

Comment: No, there is no such caching mechanism as you suggest. There must be some other issue.

Comment: Are you saving the file as "UTF-8"?

Comment: Yes, I save the files as UTF-8 without BOM

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of caching libraries that could cause an issue like yours (opcache, (outdated) APC, ...).
You usually have functionality to invalidate cached files, which enforces PHP to re-read them from the filesystem.

For example check your PHP configuration for *opcache* and (if applicable) try something like *opcache_invalidate('yourscript.php');*.

(Update: Link removed, thx @duskwuff)

Comment: The PSR-6 caching libraries you're referencing here are all used in PHP applications for caching _data_, not code. They wouldn't cause the symptoms the OP is describing.

Comment: It trows an error that no opcache function is defined. There is no information about opcache under `ini_get()` and `ini_get_all()` too?

Comment: my bad, the link has missed the point. Nevertheless the mentioned *opcache* is for caching files, not data.

Comment: @Smashzap if opcache is enabled you would see a "Zend OPCache" section in your `phpinfo()` output.
Are you using a framework, CMS, or something alike?

Comment: @Daniel in this case opcache is disabled. I don't use a framework or something else.